# How can I find the oldest active transaction in DB2 10.5 and up?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

Since the SNAPAPPL administrative view and the SNAP_GET_APPL table function are deprecated, in version 10.5 and up, how can I find the oldest active transaction by other means ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following functions to get information that used to be provided by deprecated "snap" administrative views

[MON_GET_TRANSACTION_LOG](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0059253.html)
[MON_GET_UNIT_OF_WORK](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0053939.html)
[MON_GET_DATABASE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0060769.html)

The query could look as follows:

```
select integer(mtl.applid_holding_oldest_xact)     as "Oldest Transaction",
       integer(muow.uow_log_space_used /1024 / 1024)  as "Log used(Mb)",
       integer(muow.num_locks_held)                   as "Locks Held",
       integer(muow.client_idle_wait_time)            as "Idle (seconds)",
       time(muow.uow_stop_time)                       as "UOW Stop Time",
       muow.rows_returned                             as "Rows Returned",
       muow.rows_read                                 as "Rows Read",
       integer(muow.rows_inserted)                    as "Rows Inserted",
       integer(muow.rows_updated)                     as "Rows Updated",
       integer(muow.rows_deleted)                     as "Rows Deleted"
from table(mon_get_transaction_log(-1)) mtl
     inner join
     table(mon_get_unit_of_work(null,-1)) muow
     on muow.member = mtl.member 
     and muow.application_handle = mtl.applid_holding_oldest_xact
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct! You can use the `MON_GET_TRANSACTION_LOG` table function. Here is another query found in knowledgecenter ([link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0059253.html)):

```
Select MEMBER, CUR_COMMIT_DISK_LOG_READS, CURRENT_ACTIVE_LOG, 
APPLID_HOLDING_OLDEST_XACT from table(mon_get_transaction_log(-1)) as t
order by member asc
```

**Output:**

```
MEMBER  CUR_COMMIT_DISK_LOG_READS  CURRENT_ACTIVE_LOG  APPLID_HOLDING_OLDEST_XACT
------  -------------------------  ------------------  --------------------------
     0                       9999                   1                           7
```